# Make a request via IP Spoofing

Tags: http, get, spoofing

I am working on a web **scraper** application which **scrapes** data from some B2B domain and builds its own data. What I came across was that my IP made many requests in a single day, not sure about sessions, but now the requests from my IP are not served.

Is there any ways to spoof my IP programatically, i.e. generate a request from a false IP address?

Comment: You cannot spoof your IP at the http layer, unless you use a proxy of some sort. You need to work at TCP/IP layer which then becomes platform/language specific. Also, if you manage to spoof your IP, the HTTP server will send the reply back to that IP, so you cannot receive the results.

Comment: Thanx for the suggestion. Will look at this surely. Is there any other way round?